# Azure function timer trigger

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, timer-trigger

I’m trying to create timer trigger function in the portal following this tutorial:[timer trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-scheduled-function). I try to set the **Schedule** to `0 */30 * * * *`, every 30 minutes run a time.

[image]

However after i create it, I could only see one running record,all others is `no new trace in the past`. I want to know if I did something wrong, hope some guy could help me.

Comment: CRON tester can help you test your syntax. This is your CRON in the tester. It says it cannot be parsed [Test Link](http://cron.schlitt.info/index.php?cron=0+*%2F30+*+*+*+*&iterations=10&test=Test)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose your cron expression should work and you have said you could see one record, so mostly it's the portal log problem.

The log window is a bit fragile and doesn't always show the logs. However, the log will be written to the Kudu file. To check the log you could go your function Kudu site, **Debug console** > **CMD** then go into LogFiles > Application > Functions > Function > Function Name.

There you see your function log.

It will be like the below picture.

[image]

Comment: I will check the kudu site.

Comment: You are right, i could find the running history in the log file. However is ther any way to check the log in the portal?

Answer (score 1):

it's a [NCRONTAB](https://crontab.guru/every-30-minutes) expression

An NCRONTAB expression is similar to a CRON expression except that it includes an additional **sixth field** at the beginning to use for time precision in seconds:

```
{second} {minute} {hour} {day} {month} {day-of-week}
```

to run it every 30 minute you should write "*/30 * * * *" (remove the zero in the beginning)

you can find more informations in the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp#ncrontab-expressions)

Comment: I check the ms doc, there is a sample runs once every 5 minutes with `0 */5 * * * * `, so i guess my cron is not the problem.